# Is $τ = \{A \times B : A ∈ τ_x \mbox{ and } B ∈ τ_y\}$ a topology in $X \times Y$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau_{x}$ and $\tau_{y}$ topologies in $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Is

$$
\tau = \{A \times B \vert A  \in\tau_{x} \mbox{ and } B \in\tau_{y}\}
$$

a topology in $X \times Y$?

Comment: Can you help me give a demonstration of why, please?

Comment: It's not a topology, as it's not (generally) closed under unions. But it is a basis for a topology.

Comment: Google box-topology. :)

Comment: But why it's not closed under unions?

Comment: See @Hayden's very nice illustration below.

Comment: @MeeSeongIm No, it isn't a topology on $X\times Y$. It is a basis of the product topology.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Yes, the set $\tau$ of elements forms a basis on the product space $X\times Y$ but it is not a topology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not necessarily. The issue is that $(A_1 \times B_1) \cup (A_2\times B_2)$ does not need to be of the form $A_3 \times B_3$.

For example, $([0,2]\times [0,2]) \cup ([1,3]\times [1,3])$ will look like:

[image]

However, these elements will form a *basis* for a topology on $X\times Y$, which is the product topology.

Comment: I understand why is not topology thank you very much, but to write the counterexample more "formally", as you could write this without the drawing, ie ([0,2] × [0,2]) ∪ ([1,3] × [1,3]) =?

Comment: Well, it doesn't have that nice of a form, really. Anything I'd write down would just be a variation on $([0,2]\times[0,2]) \cup ([1,3]\times [1,3])$, like 
$$\{ (x,y) \mid \text{$0\leq x,y \leq 2$ or $1 \leq x,y\leq 3$}\}$$
but I doubt that's satisfying. In general, unions of Cartesian products are pretty ugly (though intersections are quite nice, as John Griffin shows in his answer).

Comment: Ah ok, thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Santiago, are you allowed to use 'convexity' in your arguments? Because all the sets of form $A \times B$ are convex, while Hayden's union is not convex.

Comment: Also, it's a minor point, but since the problem deals with open sets, you should probably use $(0,2)$ instead of $[0,2]$

Comment: @user275313 I'm using the discrete topology. ;)

Comment: @Hayden: Touché     ;--}

Answer (score 2):

Not quite. It's not hard to see that $\emptyset$ and $X\times Y$ are both in $\tau$. Using the fact that
$$ (A\times B) \cap (C\times D) = (A\cap C) \times (B\cap D),
$$
one can obtain that $\tau$ is closed under finite intersections.
However unions may fail. To see why, consider $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology. Then the sets $(0,2)\times (0,1)$ and $(0,1)\times(0,2)$ are products of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$, but their union is not of the desired form.

However, as others have mentioned, these sets do form a basis for the product topology of finitely many spaces, or of the box topology of arbitrarily many.